# EveryCircuit mosfet specs?

Tags: mosfet, simulation

Has anyone ever used the circuit simulation 'EveryCircuit'?  I bought an android license for it back in 2012 and used it quite a bit for simple circuit tests prior to building something as a lay person.  It was a useful way to see a circuit work to better understand it.
I just went back to use it again to try to figure out something on a mosfet switch circuit, but the values they use for adding a mosfet and configuring it are units I can't seem to find on a datasheet anywhere. Things like:

width/length (in micro/nano meters)
VTO, KP and Lambda

They don't seem to have any documentation available anywhere any longer and their forums appear to only be for posting software circuits.

Can anyone point me toward how I obtain these off the values on a datasheet so I can tweek the sim to match the components I have on hand?

Comment: There are books on the subject of measuring and then extracting various Spice parameters for non-linear device models. For example, half of Ian Getreu's "Modeling the Bipolar Transistor" is dedicated to instrumentation, the setup of same, and how to extract Spice parameter values from the resulting measurements and curves. Back before everything became a matter of just "buying an opamp" there were whole divisions within Tektronix (STS) that did ONLY one thing -- make equipment that allowed you to extract such parameters from BJTs and MOSFETs and JFETs. Those days are gone. Opamps über alles.

Comment: Of course, you can just go look up a Spice model for the device you want (or something close, if you can't find one for it.) This is good enough for some uses. But keep in mind that MOSFET parameters vary very widely on some parameters, device to device in the same bag. Same with BJTs, though I like to think it's not quite as bad as with MOSFETs. And JFETs? They are all over the place. Even in the same family. So your circuit may work with the Spice model you have, but not work with the circuit you make. Global and local negative feedback is your friend.

Comment: I ended up posting a generic circuit with just two mosfets in their 'community' and someone gave me a link to a circuit-post that had a cross-reference in the description for common FETs http://everycircuit.com/circuit/5282567524450304

Answer (score 1):

you can search online in alldatasheet.com or alltransistors.com

alltransistors.com have almost everything detailed with a very useful function searching similar transistor, yes it does have mosfet spec. 
but i doubt there is lambda and KP spec, i never understand either, because there is only Vds Vgs Id, etc even on the original and official specification there is no Lambda spec

there is explanation better from the other user of everycircuit :
http://everycircuit.com/circuit/5927322113015808/

http://everycircuit.com/circuit/6148524605702144/n-mosfet-lambda-adjustment-in-ec

basically they call it leave it to default setting..

Answer (score 0):

Per Cubic273.15 posted [link,](https://everycircuit.com/circuit/6148524605702144/n-mosfet-lambda-adjustment-in-ec) you can just click on the wrench and it shows you a specific set of level 1 design and process values.

[image]

I doubt you will find a data sheet showing specific device W,L values as these are internal design parameters. You can just try your own values there. The other parameters \$Vto, \lambda, Kp\$ are typically provided by a design foundry. There are also ways to extract these values on a test bench. Keep in mind, those values very rudimentary and nowadays, the design parameters and models are much more complex.